# php_imagick.dll is not loading on IIS 7.5 on windows server 2008 using plesk manager

Tags: imagemagick, iis-7.5, php-5.3, windows-server-2008-r2

i am using virtual dedicated server and the configuration is windows server 2008 R2 standered edition. I recently upgraded it to PHP version 5.3.10(thread Safe version). I Installed PHP ImageMagick version /ImageMagick-6.6.3-0-Q16-windows-dll.exe by following the steps given at http://gary-greendale.blogspot.in/2011/01/install-php-imagemagick-and-imagick-for.html

I got my php ImageMAgick working finally(after nth attempts) using command prompt. but now i am tryin to use php_imagick.dll to load iMagick Library with PHP.

After thousands of efforts and lots of  dll files replaced (tried many versions)

```
http://valokuva.org/builds/
http:+//valokuva.org/builds/ext/vc9/nts/imagick/2011-04-25_1849/
http:+//valokuva.org/builds/ext/vc9/ts/imagick/2011-04-25_1849/
```

and many other thread and non thread safe versions. Please suggest me the correct version of the php_imagick.dll so that i can get it running on my server.

I am sure the issue is related to php_imagick.dll's version.

Its kinda urgent now  help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that those versions at valokuva.org are VC9 and versions of ImageMagick after 6.6.2-10 are VC10. Basically, you're going to need to downgrade to an earlier version of ImageMagick if you want to run it with those IMagick binaries.

I know this because I just dealt with it today and found the solution on an Apache forum. Once I downgraded to 6.6.2-10, it started working.

[Here's a link to the forum post...](http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=4029)

Comment: Thanks Greg, though it is a late reply, this really helped me. Cheers